# How to stub the function inside a class like function sinon

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

```
//foldercontroller.js file

// Self invoking function.
(function()
{
    ....
    lib.FolderController = FolderController;

    function FolderController(thePath)
    {
         .... // Some other initializations and other functions
        this.getFileList = getFileList;
        function getFileList()
        {
            return someArray;
        }
    }


})();
```

I want to stub getFileList function above in the code below. I am using sinon library. I did something but I am hopeless

```
// FileCacheTest.js file Here I want to test some feature

var fileList = ["a","b","c"];
var filesStub = sinon.stub(lib.FolderController, "getFileList")
                     .callsFake(function fakeFn(){
                           return fileList;
                     });
```

I got this result:

**TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property getFileList as function**

Use case is below. I want to get the fileList as I want when the `folderController.getFileList();` is called

```
var folderController = new lib.FolderController(theDirectory);

var files = folderController.getFileList();
```

**My question is how can I stub this getFileList function ?**

Comment: getFileList is undefined as it is defined on instanciation... I think you'd want to either put it in prototype or instanciate the object.

Answer (score 0):

Your `lib.FolderController`is a function. 
Inside this function you have a property `getFileList` which is again a function.

So what you can do is:

1) Instantiate your object instead of assigning that to a function:

`lib.FolderController = new FolderController('mypath');`

2) Trying to stub in this way:

```
var filesStub = sinon.stub(lib.FolderController(), "getFileList")
                     .callsFake(function fakeFn(){
                           return fileList;
                     });
```

But remember to add `return this;` at the end of the `FolderController` function, otherwise it won't return an object and you can't stub a method over a non object.

I don't know what you are doing, so check the one which fits more your needs.

Comment: I tried the second solution but gave TypeError: Should wrap property of object

Comment: @gunescelil Does your function return an object? If not, you can't stub in that way because your function doesn't return an object. I was sure that the function was returning an object at the end. When you use the stub you need an object as first parameter. But if you are not returning an object, the method seems to be private, and in general private methods don't need to be tested. You will test them through the public methods which call them

Comment: Yes the getFileList function returns an object.